# Does Redis / Memcached / MongoDB (or any NoSQL systems) support MySQL's ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, redis, memcached, nosql

I need to keep track of which user has visited which page how many times.

In MySQL I'd do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO stats (user_id, url, hits)
VALUES (1234, "/page/1234567890", 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits = hits + 1;
```

In the table `stats` `(user_id, url)` is `UNIQUE`

I'm looking to find the fastest system for this purpose. As this is just for stats keeping durability is not important.

Does Redis or MongoDB or Memcached or any other NoSQL systems support such a feature? How would you implement this to get the highest performance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In MongoDB the equivalent concept is called an `upsert` (detailed info [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-update%28%29).)

This basically means: "Go look for the document with this key- if it exists, apply this update. If it doesn't exist, create it and apply this update."

So for example, in your case  you could do something like this in mongo:

`db.stats.update({user_id:1234, url:"/page/1234567890"}, {$inc:{hits:1}}, true)`

The first time this gets called (on an empty db), it would insert this document:

`{user_id:1234, url:"/page/1234567890", hits:1}`

Subsequent calls would simply increment the value of `hits`.

In Redis, you could accomplish this by just using the Redis `INCR` command, where your key is based on the values you need to qualify it as unique. The first call to `INCR` just sets the value to 1 if it doesn't exist yet. For example:

```
INCR "uid:1234:url:/page/1234567890"
> 1
INCR "uid:1234:url:/page/1234567890"
> 2
```

etc.

As for how to implement this for highest performance, this depends on what you mean by "performance" and what your use case is. For example, using Redis `INCR` command is likely faster than MongoDB, but you sacrifice capabilities for indexing and querying, as well as flexibility in your data model. These are tradeoffs that you will need to decide based on your particular situation.

Comment: Thank you! How many upserts per second can Mongo do on a quadcore commodity server - what's your experience?

Comment: I can't give a meaningful answer to this as it varies greatly based on your schema design, amount of RAM, size of data set, and other factors. Your best bet is to write a simple benchmark test that mimics what your app will do to evaluate performance.

Comment: @Continuation, you should definitely benchmark. Also be aware that MongoDB has different levels of "write concerns" or "write safety". By default, most drivers use "fire and forget" writes which are really fast but don't throw errors (*like duplicate key*). So be sure that you are testing the right level of data safety when you benchmark.

Comment: I'm getting about 12k upserts/sec on my macbook pro here, with a simple document searching on an indexed field and then updating a count--1 million docs in the collection. It's only using one CPU core.